# Is "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" a security risk?

Tags: security, environment-variables, shared-library

We know `ld.so` searches for libraries in directories specified by the environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but regular users could run:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=dir1:dir2...
```

They can save infected library in a path with higher priority than the original one so that `ld.so` finds that one instead of the trusted library in the `ld.so.cache`.

Is this a risk?
How can we disable writing to this environment variable for regular user?

Comment: Thanks @Byte Commander  for editing. my English is not good:)

Comment: No problem, it's better than the average :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not a security risk at all, because you can always only set environment variables for your current environment (e.g. current Bash session) and, using the `export` command, its child environments (scripts you launch, subshells, etc.). It's impossible to escalate an environment variable created or modified into the parent environment. This includes that it's impossible for regular users to make system-wide changes, of course.

So the only environment that would be affected if you run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` is your current shell and any subshells of it you might spawn later. Let's say you change the lookup path to include infected libraries at the beginning i.e. with the highest priority. Then you run an executable that loads one of the infected libs without even knowing. What happens now?

You have malicious code (from the infected library) running under your own user account with regular non-admin privileges. This might sound bad, but actually... so what? It runs with regular user privileges which again means it can not affect the entire system. By the way, directly running an executable with the same malicious code would have been much easier than modifying the library lookup path and waiting for a normal executable to load it.

**Conclusion:** A regular user can only modify their own library lookup path, which means they can also only load those libraries themselves under their regular user account with regular non-system-wide privileges. That said, it makes no difference whether they force loading an infected library or directly run an infected executable. You would gain absolutely nothing if that environment variable could not be overridden by users.

**PS:** There are also executables which have the *setuid* or *setgid* flag set, which means they will not run as the user/group of the one who runs them, but of the one who *owns* them. For example the `sudo` executable is owned by root and has the *setuid* flag set, which means it always runs as root when executed. For security reasons, the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is ignored by executables with one of the *setuid/setgid* flags set to make sure that the regular user can not make an executable running with root privileges to load arbitrary libraries.
<sub>*(Thanks to @Rinzwind for pointing this out!)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am reading a book it says " the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
is considered to be a security risk because it might allow unauthorized programs access to system libraries accidentally or otherwise expose system library paths to unauthorized users." what the means?

Comment: @Sinoosh I can't really think of a reason why it should be a security issue if an untrusted application knows the location of my system libraries. If everything is configured correctly and you have not messed with permissions, they should be owned by root and not writeable by anyone else, which means there is no risk that they get infected or modified in any way (unless you run the untrusted application as root, but you won't do this, right?)

Comment: @Sinoosh see http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html

Comment: @ Byte Commander , I am agree with you not with Author:)

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is of course a security issue when you are loading a malicious library in the first place and change how a binary behaves.

Comment: @heemayl But the only binaries which would be affected are those executed by the regular user after he changed the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This can not cause a security issue on system level. Or am I not correctly understanding you?

Comment: Its a malicious library we are talking about. No one could not be sure that it would not make any privilege escalation stuff or doing something nasty.

Comment: @heemayl But the risk of privilege escalation is just as high as if an ordinary executable got downloaded anywhere and executed. It makes no sense to inhibit the obscure threats if the easy paths are still open.

Comment: This does not make any sense. The question was about security and you are arguing which is one less secure..

Comment: @heemayl Getting an executable to load a specific library is a way to execute the code in the library, which might be malicious if it is from an untrusted source and its location got manually added to the lib path by the regular user. Of course that is a way to execute arbitrary code, but always only with the privileges of the current regular user, just like executing any normal executable. I see no reason at all why the complicated way via an infected library should be more dangerous than if the user directly runs an infected executable.

Comment: @heemayl However, please feel free to post your own answer explaining your doubts.